# Why is my VSCode debugger stopping in the Method.class file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

All of a sudden, the debuggger stops at `return ma.invoke(obj, args);`in the `java.lang.reflect.Method.class` file.

And it ignores my own breakpoints.

I'm under release:

```
Version: 1.36.1
Commit: 2213894ea0415ee8c85c5eea0d0ff81ecc191529
Date: 2019-07-08T22:55:08.091Z
Electron: 4.2.5
Chrome: 69.0.3497.128
Node.js: 10.11.0
V8: 6.9.427.31-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 5.0.0-050000-generic snap
```

I have the following extensions:

```
Name: Java Extension Pack
Id: vscjava.vscode-java-pack
Description: Popular extensions for Java development and more.
Version: 0.7.1
Publisher: Microsoft
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-pack

Name: Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat
Id: redhat.java
Description: Java Linting, Intellisense, formatting, refactoring, Maven/Gradle support and more...
Version: 0.47.0
Publisher: Red Hat
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java

Name: Debugger for Java
Id: vscjava.vscode-java-debug
Description: A lightweight Java debugger for Visual Studio Code
Version: 0.20.0
Publisher: Microsoft
VS Marketplace Link: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscjava.vscode-java-debug
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing a `Java: Clean the Java language server workspace` solved the issue.

Comment: Sorry but I cannot

Comment: It's Ok.I will try